# Java version update

Tags: java, version

when i run java -version in command prompt it shows java version "10.0.2". But for javac -version it shows the older version which is javac 1.8.0_121. I have edited the java_home,jre_home and path variables and restarted the system also

Comment: You should uninstall jdk 10.0.2 and then install 1.8 after that you will not face this issue. i have also experienced the same problem. You can also check through control panel that which version is installed on your system.

Answer (score 0):

So what is the question?
But in this case, I think you should try to uninstall and then reinstall JDK.